# reading animations.length, length is zero - I don't remember how to set up my animation

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, rendering

When downloading the glb it says it has some animations, but when I check with console.log(gltf.scene) it's empty!?

I have used this particular model before with animations and seen it running.
But I can't recall how I did and don't properly understand how to implement the ThreeJs docs manual. So I assume the problem is that the animations are there but not accessable due to something with my setup.

This is what I currently use:

```
    //gltf-object
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load('/localhost/glb-objekts/stegosaurs_SStenops.glb', (gltf) => {
gltf.scene.position.set(0, 40, 130);
gltf.scene.visible = true;
model = gltf.scene;
scene.add(model);
let skeleton = new SkeletonHelper(model)
scene.add( skeleton );   
// gltf-animation
const clips = model.animations;
const mixer = new AnimationMixer( model );
const clip = new AnimationClip().findByName( clips, 'walk1' );
const action = mixer.clipAction( clip );
action.play();
console.log(model);
```

} );

```
function render() { mixer.update( deltaSeconds ); renderer.render(scene, camera); requestAnimationFrame(render);}
```

The model is showing and the only error says: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') at AnimationClip.resetDuration"